# Online short story about a robot plugged to a wall that becomes sentient

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I’m looking for an online (very) short story written in English that I read about 10 years ago.

The story is about a couple of scientists making repeated experiments on a robot that is attached by a power cord to the wall. During the experiments the robot becomes sentient but cannot communicate this to the scientists, in fact, the only interaction the robot can perform is to move forward/backwards.

The story is written from the robot's perspective as it tries to follow the scientists' verbal instructions, so that they will understand it has become sentient. When instructed to move forward with the robot will comply every time, although it means the power cord will detach and the robot will “die”. Each time the robot dies it desperately hopes that the scientists​ will reconnected the cord to the outlet so it can  “come back to life”.

As far as I can remember the scientists are unaware of the robot’s sentience, and each time the  power cord is plugged back and the robot comes back online, it will hear the scientists repeating their protocol: “ Experiment no. 44, testing bla bla...”